# What is the fittest inheritance type in EF for my case?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i have the flowing classes:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    //...
    public DateTime CteatedAt{get;set;}
    public DateTime UpdatedAt{get;set;}
    // ....
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    // ...
    public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;}
    public DateTime UpdatedAt{get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

and i want the database tables to be looks like:
 - People table:(id,...,createdat, updatedat);
 - Employee table:(id, ..., createdat, updatedat);

and in the code, when i need the person creation date i will do:
Employee em ;
datetime pcd = (Person)em.CreatedAt;
and when i need employee creation date:
datetime ecd = em.CreatedAt;

please what is the fittest inheritance type for my case?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you're going is too complicated. If I understand you right - you need to separate `PersonCreateDate` and `EmployeeCreateDate`.

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime CreateDate {get;set;}
}

public class Employee
{
    public DateTime CreateDate {get;set;}
    public virtual Person BasedOnPerson {get;set;}
}
```

In database, `Employee` must have a foreign key to `Person`.

Comment: thanks @JesseJames but i want to make the code so easy i do not like using of the navigation properties.